# How to solve the recursion error in my video gray scale converter

Tags: python, opencv, recursion, kivy, pyinstaller

I am working on a desktop app which can convert a video to gray scale video using Kivy and OpenCV.

But after using the `pyinstaller` with this below command

```
pyinstaller --name VideoCartoonizer --windowed --onefile main.py
```

I got an error showing

> Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Below is my code:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips, VideoClip

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class VideoCartoonizer(App):

    def build(self):

        # create the GUI

        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # select input file button

        self.select_input_button = Button(text='Select Input File', size_hint_y=0.1)

        self.select_input_button.bind(on_press=self.select_input_file)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.select_input_button)

        # input file path label

        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='Or enter the input video file path:', size_hint_y=0.1))

        # input file path text input

        self.input_file = TextInput(size_hint_y=0.1)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.input_file)

        # convert button

        self.convert_button = Button(text='Convert to cartoon', size_hint_y=0.1)

        self.convert_button.bind(on_press=self.convert_video)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.convert_button)

        # output file path label

        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='Output file path:', size_hint_y=0.1))

        # output file path text input

        self.output_file = TextInput(size_hint_y=0.1, readonly=True)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.output_file)

        return self.layout

    def select_input_file(self, *args):

        # create the file chooser

        file_chooser = FileChooserListView(filters=['*.mp4'])

        # create the popup

        popup = Popup(title='Select Input File', content=file_chooser, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))




# set the callback for when a file is selected

        def on_selection(instance,selected_file):

            self.input_file.text = selected_file[0]

            popup.dismiss()

        file_chooser.bind(selection=on_selection)

        # open the popup

        popup.open()

    def convert_video(self, *args):

    # get the input file path

        input_file = self.input_file.text

    # define the video processing function

        def process_image(image):

        # resize the image while maintaining aspect ratio

            aspect_ratio = image.shape[1] / image.shape[0]

            target_width = 640

            target_height = int(target_width / aspect_ratio)

            image = cv2.resize(image, (target_width, target_height)) 

        # convert to grayscale

            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            return gray

    # process the input video and save the output

        output_file = input_file.replace(".mp4", "_cartoon.mp4")

        input_video = VideoFileClip(input_file)

    # create a queue to keep track of the frames that need to be processed

        frame_queue = list(input_video.iter_frames())

    # create an output video clip with the same parameters as the input video

        output_video = None

        for i, frame in enumerate(input_video.iter_frames()):

            if output_video is None:

                output_video = VideoClip(

                    lambda t: process_image(frame_queue.pop(0)),

                    duration=input_video.duration

            )

            else:

                output_video = concatenate_videoclips([

                    output_video,

                    VideoClip(

                        lambda t: process_image(frame_queue.pop(0)),

                        duration=input_video.duration

                    )

                ])

    # write the output video

        output_video.write_videofile(output_file, codec='mpeg4')
```

Error:

```
 File "logging\__init__.py", line 1084, in emit

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1084, in emit

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1084, in emit

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1084, in emit

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'


File "logging\__init__.py", line 1657, in callHandlers

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 950, in handle

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1089, in emit

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1002, in handleError

  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1454, in warning

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1585, in _log

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1595, in handle

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1657, in callHandlers

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 950, in handle

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1089, in emit

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1002, in handleError

  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1454, in warning

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1585, in _log

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1595, in handle

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1657, in callHandlers

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 950, in handle

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1081, in emit

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 925, in format

  File "kivy\logger.py", line 291, in format

  File "copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy

  File "copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct

  File "copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy

  File "copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict

  File "copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy

  File "copy.py", line 210, in _deepcopy_tuple

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Want to make my video gray scaling work as a exe file, as it is working fine in any text editor

Comment: Please consider using the block formatting tool on code and logs. As you can see, this question is not very readable. Would you edit it?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The part that gives away what the cause of the problem is comes from the error traceback: `File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write`. It seems to be that the recursion error is being caused by Kivy, so a quick google search for `kivy logging recursion depth error python` reveals [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8074#issuecomment-1364595283) answer to an open issue on the kivy github. This seems to describe your problem, so I would suggest trying out the workarounds in that issue and comment below if this doesn't work for you.